# Is there a way to display Interstate Rest Areas on Google Maps Navigation?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, motorola-droid, gps, google-maps

I've had several instances where this information would have been useful when navigating w/ Moto Droid, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to get to interstate (USA) rest areas in Google Maps Navigation.  Are they grouped in with something else? Called something else?

I was thinking of suggesting this to Google, but I wanted to make sure it wasn't already there and missing it.

Comment: while looking for the version number (4.5) to add to this question, i found an option to add from my maps: Layers --> More Layers --> My Maps --> select a map created ahead of time (by myself or others).  it gets the job done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit of a hack.

Thanks to an answer in the [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2171/does-a-nationalusa-interstate-rest-stop-rest-area-dataset-exist), I was able to contact the owner of a web mashup (driven by a google spreadsheet) who created an KML export link.

http://tables.googlelabs.com/exporttable?query=select+col3%2Ccol1%2Ccol2%2Ccol4%2Ccol5%2Ccol6%2Ccol7%2Ccol8%2Ccol9%2Ccol10%2Ccol11%2Ccol12%2Ccol13%2Ccol14%2Ccol15%2Ccol16%2Ccol17%2Ccol18+from+261434+&o=kmllink&g=col17

Copy/Pasting this link into the search box in Google Maps on my droid displayed the rest areas on the map.

There's a limit to the number of points the map will display out the KML, so if you are zoomed out too far, you'll only get a cluster of points.  So make sure you are zoomed in close enough--having a few states visible should still work and be no problem.

When the map points load, the extent changes. I guess it's to the extent of all the points that were loaded from the KML.

Comment: Nice find. I'll have to try that.

Comment: I'm also attempting to contact google mobile team and see if they would consider adding this type of data as a layer--that would be a lot more convenient.